# Does Objective-C have reflection?

Tags: objective-c, reflection

I'm doing research about Objective-C, and I'd like to know if it has the concept of reflection. None of the documents I've found so far describes reflection.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C

Comment: Objective-C have a much more powerful reflection ability than Java have. You can know more from [Apple's Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048)

Comment: You will get a better answer if you explain precisely what *you* mean by "reflection." Like many languages, ObjC has some kinds of reflection and not others.

Comment: @son.vu note that you can accept an answer by clicking the big white checkmark shown to the left of the answer.

Comment: @RobNapier . OK . i'm want research about all concept of Reflection in Objective-C . 
Besides, i also want research about Abstract Class in Obj-C . hik hik

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are runtime functions described in [Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) which allows not only querying for features of a class or an instance, but also adding a method, or even creating a new class at runtime. I say this is a very dynamic kind of reflection, which was not usually available to C-based languages. [Mike Ash's wrappers](https://github.com/mikeash/MAObjCRuntime) is an Objective-C wrapper around that. Again, it can even add methods!  The base class of Cocoa, `NSObject`, also provide wrappers for many of the runtime functions, see [`NSObject` protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject). For example

```
     [foo respondsToSelector:@selector(bar:)];

     if([foo isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){ ... }
```

does what the method names say. You can even add a method on the fly. For example,

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import <objc/runtime.h>

   @interface Foo:NSObject
   {
   }
   @end
   @implementation Foo
   -(void)sayHi
   {
        NSLog(@"Hi! from %@",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
   }
   +(BOOL)resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)sel
   {
        Method method=class_getInstanceMethod(self,@selector(sayHi));
        class_addMethod(self,sel,method_getImplementation(method),method_getTypeEncoding(method));
        return YES;
   }
   @end

   int main(){
    NSAutoreleasePool*pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        Foo* foo=[[Foo alloc] init];
        [foo aeiou];
        [foo bark];
        [foo mew];
        [pool drain];
        return 0;
  }
```

This produces the output

```
  Hi! from aeiou
  Hi! from bark
  Hi! from mew
```

What it does is as follows:

1. `SEL` is the variable which represents the sent message (or method call, in the other terminology.)
2. Objective-C runtime calls `resolveInstanceMethod:` of a class if a message sent to an instance is not implemented in the class
3. So, in this case, I just copy an implementation of a predefined method called `sayHi` to that method's implementation.
4. From the method, you can use `_cmd` to see what was the selector used in calling the method. So, even from a single `sayHi` implementation, we can get different output.

Some of the standard Cocoa's implementation (Key-Value-Coding, Key-Value-Observing and Core Data in particular) uses the runtime to dynamically modify the class.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, Objective-C has reflection (and abstract classes).  Whether that reflection fits your needs or not is a different question.

Reflection in Objective-C is surprisingly flexible for a C derived language.  You can ask a class what methods it implements or you can modify and/or add methods to existing classes.  You can even create new classes on the fly or change the class of any instance at any time.

A typical Objective-C program **does none of theses things** (at least not directly) save for occasionally calling `respondsToSelector:` or `conformsToProtocol:`.   While Objective-C is a fully dynamic, reflective, object oriented language, that doesn't mean that such patterns are encouraged or typically used.

You might find my answers to these questions interesting:

[In Objective C, how to find out the return type of a method via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447559/in-objective-c-how-to-find-out-the-return-type-of-a-method-via-reflection/7447641#7447641)

[Does Objective-C have a Standard Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833756/does-objective-c-have-a-standard-library)

[Smalltalk runtime features absent on Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509449/smalltalk-runtime-features-absent-on-objective-c/7509594#7509594)

And, of course, the runtime is [very well documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048).   As is [the language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/introduction/introobjectivec.html).   Or you could [read the source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/).

Comment: Do you have any idea how to set the actual property once you have found it using Reflection?  I have a question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/25538890/1735836

Answer (score 1):

I guess I don't know what aspect of reflection you're looking for. Are you looking for how to determine which class a given variable is? If so, check this out: [Objective-C class -> string like: [NSArray className] -> @"NSArray"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331983/objective-c-class-string-like-nsarray-classname-nsarray)

```
// Get a object's class name
if ([NSStringFromClass([foo class]) compare:@"NSSomeObject"] == NSOrderedSame) {...}

// Does an object have a method
[foo respondsTo:@selector(method:)]
```

Are you looking for more than just this?

Comment: oh ! my manager require research about Abstract Class and Reflection in Objetive-C . I tried to find out but to no result  , so I must ask everybody  :( .
P/S : thanks a lot .

Comment: Huh? Is it related to your work? You need to pay us part of your salary :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a flock of [methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) that can access various properties of a class and, presumably, "peek" and "poke" at some object internals.  I've never played with them, and a little reading that I've done suggests that they're far from perfect, but they do appear to offer some ability for "reflection", similar to the Java concept.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to set the actual property once you have found it using Reflection?  I have a question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/25538890/1735836